# Prior elicitation with Normal-Gamma or Normal-Inverse-Gamma

Tags: regression, bayesian, prior, hyperparameter, elicitation

I am looking for a way to have experts elicit a prior for a Normal-Inverse-Gamma Bayesian linear regression model. Is there any material suggesting intuitive ways to go about this?